# How to link to a particular post id

Tags: python, django

i am working on a project in Django and i am having issues on how i can link to a particular post id. I have list of posts on homepage and also an ellipsis on top of each post, when ellipsis is clicked it popup a modal. In the modal i have a link 'edit post' that takes me to update_post.html, but when i click on the second post ellipsis and modal popup, then i click on the 'edit post' link it takes me to update_post.html but only takes the latest post id in url instead of the second post id in url. For example: it takes me to (first post): http://127.0.0.1:8000/update/status/11/ instead of (second post): http://127.0.0.1:8000/update/status/17/

home.html

```
{% if all_images %}
{% for post in all_images %}
<ul>
<li class="ellipsis float-right">
{% include 'newfeeds_modal.html' %}
</li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

newfeeds_modal.html

```
<!-- User Ellipsis -->
{% if post.poster_profile == request.user %}
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#homeuserellipsisModal" class="font-small float-right">
        <img src="{{ '/static/' }}images/more_icon.png" width="16" height="16" alt="more" class="float-right" style="position:relative;top:13px;left:10px;">
    </a>
    <!-- Home User Ellipsis Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade animated fadeIn" id="homeuserellipsisModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content w-75 mx-auto">
          <div class="card text-center w-100" id="following-modal">
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item">
              <a href="{% url 'site:update_post' post.id %}" class="black-text">
              Edit post</a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item black-text p-3" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</li>
            </ul>
          </div>          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def home_view(request):
#All posts in new feed
all_images = Post.objects.filter(
    Q(poster_profile=request.user, active=True)|
    Q(poster_profile__from_user__to_user=request.user, active=True)|
    Q(poster_profile__to_user__from_user=request.user, active=True)|
    Q(poster_profile__profile__friends__user=request.user, active=True)).distinct().exclude(
    Q(hide_post=request.user, active=True)|
    Q(poster_profile__profile__blocked_users__user=request.user, active=True))
context = {
    'all_images': all_images,
}
return render(request, 'home.html', context)

@login_required
def update_post_view(request, id):
#update post
post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
edit_form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
if request.method == "POST":
    if edit_form.is_valid():
        edit_form.save()    
        return redirect('site:comments', id=id)
else:
    edit_form = PostForm(instance=post)

context = {
    'edit_form': edit_form,
}
return render(request, 'update_post.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by making the *id attribute* unique with the post `pk`

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#homeuserellipsisModal{{post.pk}}" class="font-small float-right">
```

Now also in the modal

```
<div class="modal fade animated fadeIn" id="homeuserellipsisModal{{post.pk}}" role="dialog">
```